# GWT - FlexTable - cannot see added row

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, event-handling

I am writing a test to see how event handlers should work but it seems I am doing something wrong here because I cannot see the added Widget to the flextable :(

Here is my code snippet

Composite A:

```
B b=new B();
Button addItemButton = new Button("+");
        addItemButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
            public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
                Window.alert("Hello world!");
                b.addItem(itemTable);
            }

        });
```

Composite B:

```
public void addItem(FlexTable itemTable)
    {



        itemTable.add(new C());
    }
```

Composite C:

```
...

Button removeRow=new Button();
removeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
                public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {

                    itemTable.removeRow(?);
                }

            });
```

I mean nothing adds to the itemTable when I run it as GWT app in my default Internet Browser. How to refresh ItemTable or something to see its added or removed rows?

Any useful comments are appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to look more closely at the GWT Stocks example.  This is the code section which actually adds the row:

```
 // Add the stock to the table.
    int row = stocksFlexTable.getRowCount();
    stocks.add(symbol);
    stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 0, symbol);
```

The call to `stocksFlexTable.setText()` is what creates the row in the table and sets the text.  So your code for `B` and `C` should look more like this:

```
//In Composite B
public void addItem(FlexTable itemTable) {  
  int row = itemTable.getRowCount();
  itemTable.setText(row, 0, symbol);
  itemTable.add(new C(row));
}

//In Composite C, the constructor saves the int argument as the field 'row'
Button removeRow=new Button();
removeButton.addClickHandler(new ClickHandler() {
  public void onClick(ClickEvent event) {
    itemTable.removeRow(C.this.row);
  }
});
```

If you just want to stack a bunch of widgets on top of each other (so if you don't create more than one column in the table), you should just use the [`VerticalPanel`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/VerticalPanel.html).  It's `add()` method will do what you were expecting.

Answer (score 1):

You need to obtain and use the current row count at runtime

```
itemTable.setWidget(itemTable.getRowCount(),0,new Label("Hello world"));
```

Comment: Emm... Thanks. But how can I remove a row then? I want each row contain a widget which contains its "remove row" button which should remove its row. Most like the google example shows http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/images/CodeClientAddStock.png

Comment: But the problem is a composite contains its "row remove button". So I just wondering... is it possible to remove table row right from within another composite. To be more directive... FlexTable is in Composite A, and "remove row" button is in Composite C

Answer (score 0):

try using setWidget method.

```
public void addItem(FlexTable itemTable)
{
        itemTable.setWidget(0,0,new Label("Hello world"));
}
```

setWidgets requieres the arguments (row,col,Widget).

Comment: but I want to add items for unlimited rows number... with just add method as the google tutorial shows. how can I do that?

Comment: Haw about using VerticalPanel or FlowPanel?

Comment: Emm... I want to have ability both add and remove rows dynamically but I have no opportunity to predict how many rows are there expected to be added so I have choosed FlexTable as this google tut says http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/codeclient.html

Comment: well, in the tutorial, stocks is an ArrayList, in the array you can add and remove items, but look at section B.2, the code is stocks.add(symbol); to add the item to the LIST, and then stocksFlexTable.setText(row, 0, symbol); to add the item to the table. (row is setted to stocksFlexTable.getRowCount()).

Comment: It is quite interesting... but is it possible to add items to FlexTable as util.Vector addElement() method does or something?

Comment: the method add inherits from com.google.gwt.user.client.ui.Panel, but I really don't know what is the behavior of this method.

Comment: You know actually I was using GWT 2.2 in eclipse Ganymede and the add method worked fine as I can remember my last tests. But now I am using Helios and the final GWT version... Can it be the problem for FlexTable add method functionality? But no bug was detected or something :(

Comment: sorry, I've never used add method in FlexTable, only in Panels (Flow,Vertical, etc.).

Comment: OK... I am ready to use panels, too, if it is the optimal way. But is it possible to add and delete row element using panels?

Comment: With FlowPanel you can add Widgets to the panel (at last position) and remove (inherits from ComplexPanel) the widget with two options: by index or by widget (using equals). See http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FlowPanel.html

Comment: OK but what if I want to add elements one by one in a row? What panel that should be the vertical one?